# Why was I notified on comments where I was not mentioned?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

I commented twice on this Question : [Text disappearing and reappearing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704710/text-disappearing-and-reappearing)

Twice, the OP responded to my comments, but did not put in "@Prem", which would generally not have notified me.

Still, I got notified twice !!!

Why is that ? Is StackExchange trying out some guess-work on whom to notify , when new users do not include @username ?

Comment: I believe you get notified on any comment thread you contribute to, regardless of @

Comment: Might be true, but in one comment thread, OP accidentally used "@Prince" (who-ever he is!) & I was still NOT notified. In other comment threads, I was never notified, till now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/410681) on the main Meta:

> Additionally, if a user comments on their own post and there is only one other person who has previously commented on that post, then that person is [also notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82134/410681), even if @name is not used.

And, as far as I can see, only you and the OP posted comments on the question you linked to.